# Lie Bracket of two fields and pullback

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In which books can I find exercises related to ordinary differential equations or dynamic systems on the Lie Bracket of two fields, commutative fields and pullback of vector fields?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Any standard introductory text to differentiable manifolds will have this. There are lots of options, but classics are Spivak Volume I, Boothby, Warner, J. Lee, etc.